# After upgrading to Mac OS X Lion, I can't boot Windows anymore

Tags: windows, macos, upgrade, osx-lion, boot-camp

I upgraded to Mac OS X Lion and I can't run the installed Windows anymore. It seems the issue is that the Lion installation created extra partitions so the Windows partition has a different number one. It's disk0s4 instead of disk0s3 (if I recall correctly).

Searching online found several discussions about it but only one with a proposed solution, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3199099, essentially:

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr
bootrec.exe /FixBoot
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

which didn't work. bootrec.exe /FixBoot claims that no windows partition has been found.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rEFIt would be of help to you? I had rEFIt installed from beforehand, and my laptop seems to have survived the Lion upgrade with dual boot intact.

You could try this first [from a CD](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s1_install.html) without permanently affecting your computer, and see if it helps or not.

Comment: That's a good idea.