# Boot Windows 7 after Mac OS upgrade to Sierra

Tags: windows-7, boot, boot-camp, macos-sierra, hybrid-mbr

Upgraded Mac OS from Lion to Sierra. After that can't boot to Windows 7, successfully mounted and readable under Mac however. Boot with Bootcamp or with [newly installed](https://superuser.com/q/1185903/166606) rEFInd leads to this message:

> No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

What is correct way to fix boot:

- [bootrec.exe /FixMbr](https://superuser.com/q/317005/166606), ...
- [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)
- some other?

How to do use it and under which OS? Thanks!

---

**P.S.** 1st variant does not work - checked. However this fixed error (reported in comments [here](https://superuser.com/a/1185931/166606)) discovered by Disk Utility in partition table. Now utility reports partition is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, fixed. Seems while installing Sierra it totally erased MBR partition

1. First created rescue CD with [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/download.php) or [SystemRescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download)
2. Boot from this disk and run `gdisk /dev/sda` from terminal to create [Hybryd partition](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) - instructions under the link. In my case I converted 2nd Apple HFS+ and 4th Windows NTFS partitions to hybryd and set bootable flag to Windows's one.
3. Reboot
4. Boot from Windows 7 installation DVD, select language and run System Recovery - `Repair your computer` link, follow Windows instructions
5. Boot Windows as usual